# AngularJS Display JSON Data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am learning AngularJS and have the structure of the project set up but when i call the API that returns me JSON i can't display that in the html.

The idea is you click on the button and the returned result will be displayed in *{{answer}}*.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="xileapp">
    <div ng-controller="searchController">
        <input type="button" ng-click="search()" value="search" />
        <div>Answer: {{answer}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
xile.controller('searchController', ['personSearch', '$scope', function (personSearch, $scope) {

    $scope.search = function () {

        $scope.answer = personSearch.findPlayer();

    }

}]);
```

Service:

```
xile.service('personSearch', function ($http) {



    this.findPlayer = function() {

        $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/Crucify?api_key=222015c4-0898-4f6b-a7d5-2a23c3e0344d'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            return response;

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            return response;

        });

    };

});
```

The URL is hitting success with the correct response. How do I now get the data to display in the HTML.

Comment: findPlayer returns nothing, you need return value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not assigning any data to the `answer` (actually assigning `undefined`) because `findPlayer` doesn't return anything.

So first of all, you need to make service method return promise object:

```
this.findPlayer = function() {

    var url = 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/Crucify?api_key=222015c4-0898-4f6b-a7d5-2a23c3e0344d';

    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
        return response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        return response;
    });
};
```

then consume it in controller:

```
$scope.search = function () {
    personSearch.findPlayer().then(function(data) {
        $scope.answer = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: I get an error `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at Scope.$scope.search`

Comment: You forgot to put `return` before `$http` in `findPlayer` function. Check my code in the answer one more time.

Comment: Ahh i see, i thought i was returning something to `$scope.answer` with `return response`? But this work now thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

Angular has a Json filter you can add to the actual binding expression, once you have the json back.

```
{{ answer | json }}
```

If you want the actual json from the response, you can find it in the `data` property of the response object.

```
response.data
```

**Improvement suggestion:**

I've also provided a 'nicer' short hand for your `http` get method which I think its actually better because it'll handle any exceptions that gets thrown rather than using an error callback in your case.

```
return $http.get(apiUrl)
          .then(successCB)
          .catch(errorCB);
```

Comment: Indeed, works well with AngularJS and `<pre>{{ answer | json }}</pre>`

Answer (score 1):

Please log this JSON object and figure out proporty you want display

```
{answer: "a"}
```

then 
your view will be as

```
<div>Answer: {{answer.answer}}</div>
```

and return data from findPlayer function or promise